# what is wrong with my sql query (case when exists)

Tags: sql, t-sql, case-when

I'm trying to understand how `case when exists` expression works, there is two tables one is `trOrderHeader` which stores main info about any order. Other is `trOrderLine` which stores details about an order and there is a column `IsClosed` which indicates Order is somehow closed (canceled or completed).

So my query is below which I am trying to get OrderLineID with IsClosed column (I can do it by joins it is easy but I am trying `case when exists` expression) but all IsClosed column returns 1;

```
SELECT 
    OrderLineId,
    IsClosed = 
        CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (select * from trOrderHeader  where IsClosed=1)
        THEN    1 
        WHEN EXISTS (select * from trOrderHeader  where IsClosed=0)
        THEN   0
        END
FROM 
    trOrderLine
GROUP BY OrderLineId
```

[image: Result]

Isn't this supposed to give me if an Order is Closed write 1, if an Order is not Closed write 0?

Did I misunderstand `case when exists` expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to *correlate* the subqueries. Assuming that column `OrderId` can be used to relate the tables, then:

```
SELECT 
    OrderLineId,
    IsClosed = 
        CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (select 1 from trOrderHeader h where h.IsClosed = 1 AND h.OrderId = l.OrderId)
        THEN    1 
        WHEN EXISTS (select 1 from trOrderHeader h where IsClosed = 0 AND h.OrderId = l.OrderId)
        THEN   0
        END
FROM trOrderLine l
GROUP BY OrderLineId
```

However, the logic of the query could probably be simplified by using a `JOIN` and an aggregate function to compute the status. Something like this could be what you need:

```
SELECT l.OrderLineId, MAX(h.isClosed) IsClosed
FROM trOrderLine l
INNER JOIN trOrderHeader h ON h.OrderId = l.OrderId
GROUP BY l.OrderLineId
```